# Reworking code to avoid NetworkonMainThreadException

Tags: php, android, sql, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-networking

I have finally gotten my login application to function with my online database. I followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) tutorial. While debugging it and getting it to function with my online SQL dB, I avoided the problem of NetworkonMainThreadException by setting my minSDK down to '3'. Obviously when I bump it back up to 13+, I receive the error again. So how could I go about reworking these classes to avoid the exception? It seems like I would need to modify a lot more than one or two simple methods, correct?

Beyond LoginActivity, there is also RegisterActivity and DashboardActivity, but those are very similar to LoginActivity.

LoginActivity:

```
package com.davekelley;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import library.DatabaseHandler;
import library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private String re;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");

                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        re = res;
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

UserFunctions:

```
package library;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
package library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

JSONParser:

```
package library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                Log.v("err", line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            //this is the error
            Log.e("JSON", "json");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Bottom line is that you need to move your code into a separate thread. You can accomplish this using an AsyncTask class that you create that contains all of your network code in the doInBackground method. Then anything UI related will be called in your onPostExecute method. There are plenty of good examples of creating an AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do anything on the main(UI) thread that takes a lot of time, or takes an uncertain time, like networking. You will have to modify your source, so every networking activity gets on a different thread. A very good solution for this, is to use AsyncTask. This way, every query or whatever you want to do, gets executed in the background, not blocking the UI, thus not producing that Exception. Here it is detailed:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Note that even if you are succeeding to do the networking on the UI thread, your app will most likely freeze.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can detect the slowness when I hit login or register, visibly. I knew right from the beginning that I would need to use AsyncTask, as I learned about it in my android book that's based on Honeycomb. I guess my question is, do I find a way to lump all of this code into one method, doInBackground?

Comment: Basically, AsyncTask have 3 main methods, onPreExecute, doInBackGround and onPostExecute. Typically, you will want to do initialization, fetching neccessary datas from the UI thread in the onPreExecute, you should do the networking and the proccessing in the datas in the doInBackground, and you should interact and set the results in the onPostExecute. I think there is no strict algorhythm to convert simple code to AsyncTasks, since every code is different, and doing something different, so you will have to do some rework :)